# Show that $f(x) = x^{n} (1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ obtains its absolute maximum at $x = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Clearly, $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ since its a polynomial. Then by the min-max theorem, $f$ has an absolute minimum and maximum on $[0,1]$ and both are obtained by

$$f'(x) = 0 \iff nx^{n-1}(1-x) - x^{n} = nx^{n-1} - (n+1)x^{n}$$
$$ = x^{n-1}\big(\!-\!(n+1)x + n\big) = 0$$

The zeroes are

$x^{n-1} =0 \implies x = 0\quad$ and

$-(n+1)x + n = 0 \implies x = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$.

I want to show that $f$ attains its absolute maximum at $x = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$, that is,

$$f(x) \leqslant f\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right),\quad\forall x \in [0,1]$$

$$x^{n}(1-x)\leqslant\!\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\!\!\left(1\!-\!\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\!=\!\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\!\!\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$

However, I cannot construct a solid argument to show the above inequality. Any hints?

Comment: There is also a nice proof using the AM-GM inequality: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3549202/42969.

Comment: Please make the body of your MSE questions self-contained. Don't rely on the title to convey important information, because many readers won't notice it and the title may be hard to read  e.g. on phones.

Answer (score 5):

Note that$$f'(x)=x^{n-1}(n-(n+1)x)$$and that therefore $f'(x)>0$ when $x\in\left(0,\frac n{n+1}\right)$ and that  $f'(x)<0$ when $x\in\left(\frac n{n+1},1\right]$. So, $f$ is strictly increasing on $\left[0,\frac n{n+1}\right]$ and strictly decreasing on $\left[\frac n{n+1},1\right]$, and therefore $f$ attains its maximum at $\frac n{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

A polynomial is differentiable and the maximum point is either a stationary point or a boundary point.

$\frac{n}{n+1}$ is the only stationary point and it is evaluated to be positive. At the boundary, $f$ takes value $0$.

Hence $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is the global maximum.